# Webview to change height dynamically

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview. I have created groupitem and each groupitem holds a childitem. I want to resize the height of webview according to the content.
The content of WebView dyanamically changes when it displays different childitem. but the issue is when i load smaller content to bigger content, it stretches the area. but if i go from bigger content to lower it does not resize the space.It adds extra space to the content.
is there any way to do this?
here is my code

```
@Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                     boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ChildHolder holder;
            ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ChildHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                        false);
                holder.title = (WebView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textTitle_list);
                /*holder.hint = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textHint);*/
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.title.loadData("<p style='text-align:justify;font-size:15px;padding:0 10;margin:0'>" + String.format(htmlText, item.title) + "</p>", "text/html", "utf-8");

            //holder.hint.setText(item.hint);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before, and the solution was to ditch XML.

Your `WebView` cannot be init via `convertView.findViewById()` method.

Create your `WebView` object and load the contents in it.

Upon loading, add as child view into your `convertView`.

You have to use `convertView.addView(WebView)` in your ViewHolder init method.

Comment: This problem only arises in mi phone. Rest of the phone its working correctly.

Comment: Mind posting some codings for us to see?